# Как сказать "Computer Science" по-русски?

Tags: перевод, информатика

I've seen a lot of different translations for "computer science" like, "компьютер саенс" and "компьютерные науки". I was wondering which one is correct.

Comment: Компьютерные науки

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Информатика" is the closest you can get. In the Russian-language [wiki article](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0) on "Computer Science" you can find more about the history of this term in different languages. In the same article, you'll also see the term "наука о вычислительной технике", which is used but very, very limited.

The strange thing about "информатика" is that it's de-facto becoming slightly outdated (like what happened with "кибернетика" earlier), but there's no decent word or phrase we can use and claim to be modern. Nobody says "компьютер сайенс" though, that's for sure. For lack of a better term, one can just use *computer science*.

Answer (score 5):

As a college/university subject, it's "информатика".
Same as in French (l'informatique).

Answer (score 4):

Either [**компьютерные науки** or **информатика**](https://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?l1=1&l2=2&s=Computer+Science)

By no means **компьютер саенс**.